# Add group by to Oracle Query and get an error

Tags: sql, oracle

[Error after add group by and aggregation functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkPse.jpg)

[image]

This query runs good without group by and aggregate functions. After I add group by and aggregate function, it give me this error. I am a starter for query. Any advance will be helpful. The company is using Netsuite as the ERP system. Netsuite is using Oracle database. I am using ODBC connecting to their data base.

```
Select to_number(to_char(Transactions.trandate, 'YYYY')) as Year, 
       to_number(to_char(Transactions.trandate, 'MM')) as Month,
       NVL(Parent.name, Entity.name) as Customer, 
       Case 
           When Upper(Substr(Replace(Items.name,'.',''),1,4)) IN ('MEAL', 'BASE', 'BOLT', 'BITE', 'FUEL')
           THEN Upper(Substr(Replace(Items.name,'.',''),1,4))
           ELSE Items.name
       END as Item,
       Accounts.type_name as Account, 
       -sum(Transaction_lines.amount) as Sales
From Transactions
Left Join Transaction_lines ON Transactions.transaction_id=Transaction_lines.Transaction_id
Left Join Items ON Transaction_lines.item_id=Items.item_id
Left Join Accounts ON Transaction_lines.account_id=Accounts.account_id
Left Join Entity ON Transactions.entity_id=Entity.entity_id
Left Join Entity as Parent on Entity.parent_id=Parent.entity_id
Where transactions.trandate >= '2013-1-1' 
  and Transactions.transaction_type IN ('Invoice', 'Item Fulfillment', 'Cash Sale') 
  and Accounts.type_name IN ('Income', 'Expense', 'Cost of Goods Sold')

Group By 
    to_number(to_char(Transactions.trandate, 'YYYY')),   
    to_number(to_char(Transactions.trandate, 'MM')),
    NVL(Parent.name, Entity.name), 
    Case 
      When Upper(Substr(Replace(Items.name,'.',''),1,4)) IN ('MEAL', 'BASE', 'BOLT', 'BITE', 'FUEL')
           THEN Upper(Substr(Replace(Items.name,'.',''),1,4))
           ELSE Items.name
    END,
    Accounts.type_name
Order By Year, Month, Customer, Item, Account
```

Comment: Looks like it does not allow me to edit my quest once I post it and the picture did not show up. Here is the error.                                                         DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [42000] [NetSuite][ODBC 64bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Invalid SQL Syntax. All columns of the select list & order by should have set functions or be part of GROUP BY clause.[10136]
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Odbc
    DataSourcePath=dsn=Netsuite
    OdbcErrors=Table

Comment: It's better to add the error as text anyways, not as an image.

Comment: The error is clear, you need add the same not agregation column on the group by as in the select.... so `SELECT A, B, MAX(something), MIN(something)` need `GROUP A, B`

Comment: I did read through multiple times to make sure I included all the columns in group by statement.

Comment: `as Parent` isn't valid for Oracle (the `AS` keyword isn't allowed there), so presumably something is interpreting this. First guess is that it doesn't like the blank line in the middle?

Comment: Here is the response from Netsuite support.  here are the things I noticed during testing: 
• -sum(Transaction_lines.amount) is causing 'All columns of the select list & order by should have set functions
• The whole Group By statement is causing the whole error 
 
Conclusion:  
• remove -sum and Group By statement
• Grouping year, date, and amount is not possible except for the name property

Comment: Continue from above:
With ODBC though, we troubleshoot on what we think are system defects. Group By works as expected based on this sample query below:  
1. select customers.full_name, count(transactions.transaction_id)
2. from customers
3. join transactions
4. on customers.customer_id = transactions.entity_id
5. group by full_name
6. order by count(transaction_id)

Comment: @Alex, I delete any extra line there and deleted "As". Still same error.

Comment: Well, what you've posted doesn't error directly in SQL Developer, with the `AS` removed and fake tables. Can you run your query directly against the database, in SQL Developer or SQL\*Plus or similar, to check it does really work? If so then ODBC/Netsuite is mangling it somehow.

Comment: I'm wondering if it (OpenAccess, not Oracle) doesn't like the column aliases in the `order by`; as a test does it work if you replace those with the same expressions as the group-by has (maybe just one to start with); ore use `order by 1,2,3,4`; or - to see if that's the problem - remove the `order by` temporarily? (Also, not sure [if this might be helpful?](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/4811))

Answer (score 0):

You say your query without `GROUP BY` works.

Then take advantage of your alias.

```
SELECT Year, Month, Customer, Item, Account, -sum(Amount) as Sales
FROM ( 
        YOUR WORKING QUERY
     ) T
GROUP BY Year, Month, Customer, Item, Account
Order By Year, Month, Customer, Item, Account
```

Comment: New error. DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [42S22] [NetSuite][ODBC 64bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Invalid column:Year in GROUP BY.[10132]
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Odbc
    DataSourcePath=dsn=NetSuite
    OdbcErrors=Table

Comment: probably `Year` is a reserved word. try using something like `intYear`. but if you say your previous query work, try reducing the columns, maybe you have some typo.

Comment: Select Case 
      When Upper(Substr(Replace(Items.name,'.',''),1,4)) IN ('MEAL', 'BASE', 'BOLT', 'BITE', 'FUEL')
           THEN Upper(Substr(Replace(Items.name,'.',''),1,4))
           ELSE Items.name
      END as Item, -sum(Transaction_lines.amount) as Sales----I deleted all column except the Case statement column. Still the same error. Maybe I can not use Case statement with Group by? Make no sense.